# How to get all Facebook friend`s Id at once?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Earlier when I open graph.facebook.com, I can get the ID's of all the friends of mine at one place but now I am getting redirect to another developer page.

[image]

I want to know whether any method still left by which I can get the friend's ID at once. I know that `graph.facebook.com/username` feature, but I want to have all at once.

Comment: The `/me/friends` path still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using the [facebook-php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) that will return the id number for all your friends from within your application:

```
include_once('facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '<your_app_id>',
  'secret' => '<your_app_secret>',
));
$result = $facebook->api("/me/friends?limit=0");
$friends = array();
foreach ($result['data'] as $index => $friend) {
   $friends[] = $friend['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The path `graph.facebook.com/[user id]?fields=friends.fields(id)` will get what you want. You just have to make sure to send the appropriate credentials.

I recommend you use Facebook's Graph Explorer tool. It is handy to select what you want.

> `http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=511552816%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname`

Answer (score 0):

The path `graph.facebook.com/[ tools/explorer/]?fields=friends.fields(511552816%3Ffields%3Did%2C)` will get what you want. You just have to make sure to send the appropriate credentials.

I recommend you use Facebook's Graph Explorer tool. It is handy to select what you want.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=511552816%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=511552816%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname