# Facebook API v2.1 - Identify Friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

First of all, let me explain my app base case.

1.- I Register the user trought FacebookLoginButton.

2.- I get the friend list (Fb_Id, name, pic) and register/update data from these people on my db.

When i register the user, i try to identify him on my server. But i can´t (or i don´t howTo do it) with the new Fb API (v2.1).

I try to do something like "Bang With Friends", "Secret", etc. Do.

I try to use /me/taggable_friends. But the IDs (Something Like: AaIHOXcbmTgiNVgry21KqxzFLPmD2sPLjlTVS-D0e_V9-o9ssQ42RoUuz1CzNrzQkZLhSR22dnQPFAnxCIC82fKhTyhn6gsNZ0-Fl5jDKROwUQ), this ID only works to tag people; not for identify; and every time i ask for friends list, these value changes.

I think of record peoples names; and identify it by that, but wasn´t work well; because two (or more) people could have same name.

AnyOne can help me (us) with that?

Answer (score 1):

1. OK, let me be :) for my first answer on SO a while ~
2. Then, check this [get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400204/get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api-v-2-0?rq=1)
   So it seems that the  only the Send Dialog is useful for WebSite via just fb graph api.The 58 up answer clearly explained the reason And it sounds exactly should be like that.
3. However check this  [Another related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404089/how-to-get-all-facebook-friends-id-at-once) 
   Then you will see there still some way available now --cause it say in the first link all the possible doors will be shut-- by reading the profile of the friend of the only login user. It return just the same with v1.0/user/friends.
4. As I am new on js, I dont really know how to use this. If you have come up with any idea, please get in touch with [me](http://www.facebook.com/cat.roadsidecat)~ Because I am working on it toooooo...

Comment: Thanks for comment; but i tought about a solution.

I change my flowCode to asking to a new user if the name that i have in my db it´s him.

It´s not Right, but it´s ok.